# Relative Path Error in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, relative-path

Hello This is my folder Structure and i want to require/import the serverError.log file in app.js.

To require the config file i am using 
"require(../../../../../config/db.js)" and its works fine for db.js.But whenever i am giving readFile("../../../../../log/serverError.log").

Its giveing no such file or directory, open '../../../../../log/serverError.log' .But its working fine in other mechine.

So can anyone help me with this

```
/home/akash/MYB_GIT
└── mbox
    ├── config
    │   └── db.js
    ├── log
    │   └── serverError.log
    ├── services
    │   └── Node
    │       ├── api
    │       │   └── user
    │       │       └── web
    │       │           └── app.js
    │       └── modules
    │           ├── Admin
    │           │   └── api1.js
    │           ├── Guest
    │           │   └── api2.js
    │           └── user
    │               └── api3.js
    └── Test
        └── seneca_client
            ├── audit
            └── user
```

Comment: Shouldn't you go one more level up (i.e. `"../../../../../../log/serverError.log"`)?

Comment: If you have identical code on two machines - with one working and the other not working - are you sure that the current working directories are the same on both machines? That is, are you sure you are starting the node processes the same way on both machines?

Comment: yes cartant both are same way .But its working fine for other machine but not in my machine.

Comment: Gothdo i have tried that its giving the same error.

Comment: `require()` paths are relative to the script file, `readFile()` paths are relative to the directory in which you started your app.

Comment: robert see my directory structure .I have given the structure so plz tell me how to give the path

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the PATH module, specifically path.resolve().

path.resolve will generate the absolute path to the item that you've supplied to the function.

So for example your code will be:

```
readFile(path.resolve("../../../../../log/serverError.log"))
```

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html